# Как правильно составить запрос к таблице, у которой связь многие ко многим?

Tags: sql-server, запрос, sql

Таблица *Смежная* с двумя ключами

```
Код ОС  и КодПродавца
1          12
1          11
2          12
2          11
```

Таблица *Продавец*

```
КодПродавца Название
11            Сток
12            Стол
```

Как написать правильно запрос, чтобы вывести *Код ОС*, *НазваниеПолученное* (вывести из таблицы *Продавец.название*, где *Смежная.КодПродавца =Продавец.КодПродавца*, а в названии сплюсовать все значения, где *Код ОС* повторяется)?

В результате получиться должно получиться так

```
КодОС НазваниеПолученное
1     Сток,Стол
2     Сток,Стол
```

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 3):

Создайте функцию, которая по Коду ОС проходит по объединению таблиц и возвращает список названий, разделённых запятой. Потом сделайте запрос, возвращающий DISTINCT от кодов ОС и связанные с ним склеенные названия.

А вообще, у меня такое ощущение, что оптимальнее эти данные обрабатывать на клиенте.

Вообще, склеивание названий через запятую - это по семантике агрегатная функция.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT table1.field, table1.field2, table2.field3 
 FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 
 ON table1.field_key = table2.field_key;
```

В вашем случае:

```
SELECT `Смежная`.`Код ОС`, `Продавец`.`Название` as `Название полученное`
FROM `Смежная` LEFT JOIN `Продавец` 
     ON `Смежная`.`КодПродавца` = `Продавец`.`КодПродавца`;
```

Вместо

```
ON `Смежная`.`КодПродавца` = `Продавец`.`КодПродавца`
```

в вашем случае можно использовать

```
using(`КодПродавца`)
```

Answer (score 2):

В MySQL я бы сделал `GROUP_CONCAT`, не знаю есть ли у вас какой-то аналог:

```
SELECT `Смежная`.`Код ОС`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Продавец`.`Название`) as `Название полученное`
FROM `Смежная` 
JOIN `Продавец` 
  ON `Смежная`.`КодПродавца` = `Продавец`.`КодПродавца`
GROUP BY `Смежная`.`Код ОС`;
```

Иначе только на клиенте склеивать. `LEFT JOIN` нужен только в том случае, если Вам нужно также вывести те ОС для который продавцов нет вовсе.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT distinct p1.[Код ОС],
       ( SELECT [Название] + ','
           FROM [Продавец] p2
                inner join [Смежная] p3
                        on p2.[КодПродавца] = p3.[КодПродавца]
          WHERE p1.[Код ОС] = p3.[Код ОС]
          ORDER BY [Название]
           FOR XML PATH('') ) AS [НазваниеПолученное]
  FROM [Смежная] p1
```

Код работает начиная с MS SQL 2005, если нужны более старые версии, смотрите тут: http://www.sql.ru/faq/faq_topic.aspx?fid=130
Если знаете английский, можно большой обзор посмотреть тут: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/